# Decomposition of Chinese characters into strokes

Tags: windows, offline, language, learning

Once upon a time, there was a software that would teach you how to write Chinese characters, stroke by stroke. I can't recall its name, all I have is a screenshot, dating back to 2007.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm looking for this software, or a similar one. It should

- accept a Chinese character as input
- provide detailed steps on how to draw it, similar to the screenshot above
- run on Windows
- work offline
- ideally be gratis, but I don't know if the original was gratis, so I'll accept commercial answers as well.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the suggestions from a [Google search for "windows learn to write chinese"](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+learn+to+write+chinese)?